# Maximum value of Y axis is too large in Histogram

Tags: c#, histogram, imagej

I'm using C# to draw a histogram gray scale value of an image.
But in some image, the maximum value at y axis is too large than the other values, (e.g. maximum value is 10000, other value is 100, 200, 50,...). So I can not see the shape of histogram
[image]

When I use ImageJ app to read this image, Histogram shape locks normal.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: standard devation?

Comment: @Arphile I've updated the image.

Comment: What is the code you're using to generate the image?